# Is it possible to create a GAN model that takes no input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

Is it possible to create a GAN model that takes no input using the Keras functional/sequential API?

I'm trying to train a GAN model to generate images using the CelebA dataset. Would it be possible to use the Keras API and not pass anything to the model; rather, I would just be generating from it and have data in the [0,1] range?

Comment: No, GANs are generative models and need an input (noise vector). And this is not a programming question at all, so your question is off-topic.

Comment: It sounds like how to pass exams without books.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Comment: well, I'm trying to delete it but I can't because it has answers

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no way to have a neural network which takes no input, because then there's nothing to propagate through the neurons. The way this is usually handled in a GAN is by feeding the generator network a "latent random variable", basically a random vector representing possible features of the output.

Answer (score 0):

GANs are trained on existing data to understand the structure its underlying structure (CelebA in your case). Once a GAN is trained, there is no need to pass it an image. The generator takes in one or more (usually more than one) random numbers, from which the generator can generate a new unseen image.

Comment: I'm talking about creating a GAN model from scratch

Comment: @dedede then please update your question to mention this (and clarify what exactly "from scratch" means here).